# What is the relation between $\mathbf F$ and G,H in Green's Theorem?

Tags: greens-theorem

Green's theorem is given by:

[image]

What is the relation between $\mathbf F$ and G,H?

Comment: You know $F$ is vector valued right? $G$ is the first component and $H$ is the second component.

Comment: @Shashi Right....

Comment: Do you understand it now?

Comment: @Shashi Yes thanks...Understood...

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbf F$ is a vector function  $\mathbf F=(G,H)$ where $G$ and $H$ are the components of the vector $\mathbf F$ with respect to the basis $\hat x, \hat y$.